# Using mono's marksweep-par garbage collection

Tags: c#, linux, mono, garbage-collection

I have installed mono version 4.2.1.60 on my CentOS operating system from this [source](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-4.2.1.60.tar.bz2) by first downloading the tarball and then doing `sudo ./configure`, `sudo make` and `sudo make install` on the extracted source files.

Configure return this, which looks ok to me

```
Engine:
    Host:          x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    Target:        x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    GC:            sgen and Included Boehm GC with typed GC and parallel mark
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGALTSTACK:   yes
    Engine:        Building and using the JIT
    oprofile:      no
    BigArrays:     no
    DTrace:        no
    LLVM Back End: no (dynamically loaded: no)
```

Mono itself runs fine this way with the major collector **marksweep**.

But now I want to run mono with the SGen garbage collector and it's major collector **marksweep-par** for some tests. This is what I do according to this [description](http://docs.byteme.org.uk/manpage.php?index=1&page=mono&lang=en):

```
export MONO_GC_PARAMS=major=marksweep-par
mono-sgen testApp.exe
```

Unfortunately mono starts with this warning

> Warning: In environment variable 'MONO_GC_PARAMS': Unknown major collector 'marksweep-par'. - Using 'marksweep' instead.

Of course this is not what I want. Google did not return an answer to me when looking for this warning. Now my question is, how I can get mono to run with **marksweep-par**.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to a **old** man page (Mono 2.5) while you are running 4.2+.

You should review the man page installed on your system:

`man mono`

> `major=collector`
>
> Specifies which major collector to use. Options are `marksweep` for
>   the Mark&Sweep collector, and `marksweep-conc` for concurrent
>   Mark&Sweep. The non-concurrent Mark&Sweep collector is the default.

Comment: Hmm okay, I thought it's still correct because it's also mentioned in the mono documentation http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/working-with-sgen/ as `marksweep-par`. Thanks

Comment: Source is always the best bet for documentation, parallel collector was removed in 2014, if you really want to look at it, start with commit `8a005b8290ca0a489252f57e61c4a282a61b3998` where it was removed...